# Elementary equivalence versus equivalence between the total theory in model theory

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

In the page for elementary equivalence on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence), in the introduction, they say:

> "If N is a substructure of M, one often needs a stronger condition. In this case N is called an elementary substructure of M if every first-order σ-formula φ(a1, …, an) with parameters a1, …, an from N is true in N if and only if it is true in M."

Is it really true that it is a stronger condition? That is, are there structures N and M where Theory(N) = Theory(M) but there is no elementary mapping of N into M?

Perhaps a clarification: The wikipedia page mentions two distinct definitions of elementary equivalence(every sentence is true in both structures or false in both vs. There is a mapping of one into the other that is preserved under all formulas). What I am curious about is a counterexample to the equivalence of these two versions.

A link from one of the comments that answers my question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82157/example-of-two-structures

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are searching for an example of two structures $N,M$ with $N \subseteq M$ such that they are *elementarily equivalent* (i.e. $N \equiv M$) but such that $M$ is **not** an *elementary extension* of $N$ (i.e.$N ⊀ M$).

Comment: The wikipedia page mentions two distinct definitions of elementary equivalence(every sentence is true in both structures or false in both vs. There is a mapping of one into the other that is preserved under all formulas). What I am curious about is a counterexample to the equivalence of these two versions.

Comment: Is [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82157/example-of-two-structures) what you're looking for?

Comment: I do not "see" in Wiki two "equivalent" definition: one is *elementary embedding* (formula with free vars) and the other is *elementary equivalent* (holding for sentences only).

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I am asking for an example where the second holds and the first does not. I am essentially asking whether the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are counterexamples. Consider the language with signature $\{P_n\mid n\in {\bf N}\}$, where $P_n$ are unary predicates.

Now, consider the model $M=(2^{\bf N},P_n)_{n\in {\bf N}}$ where $P_n$ have the obvious interpretations ($x\in P_n^M$ if $x(n)=1$), and two submodels: $M_1$ which consists of those elements of $M$ which are eventually $0$, so that
$$ \forall x\in M_1\,\exists n_0\in {\bf N}\,\forall n>n_0\,(\neg P_n(x))$$ 
and its dual, $M_2$, which consists of those elements of $M$ which are eventually $1$. Then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are elementarily equivalent (they are models of the theory of infinitely many independent sets), but not only is there no elementary embedding from one into the other, there isn't even any nontrivial partial homomorphism.

Comment: I have no idea $P_n$ is and what is its obvious interpretation. Is it an unary predicate? Binary predicate? Is $P_n$ the sequences which give $1$ to $n$, or the sequences which give $0$ until $n$? There are many "obvious interpretations".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Touche. I was very tired and didn't pay enough attention, though I had certainly meant to say that they are unary predicates.